# Find all possible pairs of digits $(a,b)$ such that the six-digit number $5a4bb2$ is divisible by $9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all possible pairs of digits $(a,b)$ such that the six-digit number $5a4bb2$ is divisible by $9$

I tried to answer this question, but when I answered $(1,3)$, $(3,2)$, $(5,1)$, I got a 3/6 on the question. Can you kind people help me?

---

Okay so some of you guys helped me. Thank you. Now I have $(1,3)$, $(3,2)$, $(5,1)$, $(7,0)$, and $(0,8)$. I want to give my thanks to lulu and ty.

Comment: (7,0) also works

Comment: oh thank you so much

Comment: So does $(0,8)$.  And there are others.

Comment: thanks lulu you are amazing

Comment: I think that if you write out the necessary conditions on $a,b$ you'll be able to see that, given $a\in \{0,\cdots. 9\}$ you can always find a $b$ that works.  (warning:  sometimes there are more than one $b$ that works).

Comment: what is this symobol mean  -∈

Comment: It means "an element of".  All I was saying is that no matter which $a$ you choose amongst the possible digits you can solve for a $b$ that works.  But you must take care because sometimes more than one $b$ will work.

Comment: any (a,b) $\in N$ satisfying $2b+a = 9k - 11, k \ge 2 , k \in N$ would satisfy that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

divisibility test for 9 gives $$11+a+2b=9n$$ where $n \in N$

On rearranging , $b=\dfrac{9n-11-a}{2}$

Since, there's $2$ in denominator, numerator should be even.

Let's start with maximum value of $a$ , i.e. $a=9$

$$b=\dfrac{9n-20}{2} $$

$n$ will be even (why?)it can't be $2$,

and $$9n-20<20 \\ \implies n \le 4$$ (or else $b \text{ will be}>10$) , which infact, is the only possible value . Thus, $b=8$

If you choose $a=8$

$$b=\dfrac{9n-19}{2} \ $$  this time n will be odd (why?)

Similarly, you can work out all the cases, and each possible value of $a$ gives atmost 2 values of $b$ (that I know because I checked all possible values)

$(a, b)=(9,8), (8,4), (7,0), (7,9), (6,5), (5,1), (4,6), (3,2), (2,7), (1,3), (0,8)$

Answer (score 4):

Use the fact that, in base $10,$ a number is divisible by $9$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $9.$ So our biconditional criterion is $$9+a+2b+2\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$ which is equivalent to $$a\equiv 7-2b\pmod{9}.$$ Substituting in $b=0,1,2,\ldots, 8$ yields the solutions:
$$(7,0),(5,1),(3,2),(1,3),(8,4),(6,5),(4,6),(2,7),(0,8).$$ But this is modulo $9,$ so we can also interchange $0$ and $9$ which yields the additional solutions $(7,9),(9,8).$ None of the other digits can be swapped with any other digits of base $10$ so this is the complete list of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If the sum of the digits of a number is divisible by $9$, the number is divisible by $n$. Formally speaking, if $n$ is a $d$ digit number in base $10$:
$$n=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}{x_k \times 10^{k}}$$
Then $$\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}{x_k} \mod 9 = 0 \implies n \mod 9 =0$$
So then we need $5+a+4+b+b+2 = 11+a+2b \mod 9 = 0$ Thus
$$a+2b \mod 9 = 7$$
So $a+2b=7$ or $a+2b=16$ or $a+2b=25$ These are constrained Diophantine equations. Let's find all solutions for $(a,b)$. They are
$$(7,0);(5,1);(3,2);(1,3);(0,8);(2,7);(4,6);(6,5);(8,4);(7,9);(9,8)$$

Comment: You missed two* of the cases

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot $25$ is a valid sum as well. Thanks.